# Jenkins - Run job if other multiple jobs are successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I start a job if all 3 other jobs are successful?

Here is the scenario:

```
job1 - build module 1
job2 - build module 2
job3 - build module 3
job4 - main program
```

Run job4 (main program) if all modules build are successful (Job 1,2 and 3) so the main program can checkout all 3 modules from 3 different github repo and build the main program.

How can it be chained so its automatic?

I want all 3 jobs separate. Then Job 4 just need to check if all 3 jobs were successful and if so, it'll re-build all 3 modules inside job 4 or just pull code for all 3 modules and then proceed with other stuff. The only question is how can I check all 3 job status within jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do it if you don't do much stuff in job 1,2,3 then add those job in single jenkinsfile or groovy file with respective stages for each job and if all those jobs successful means in this case stages then schedule the job 4.

```
pipeline {

  stages {
    stage('Job 1 checkout ') {

      }
    stage('Job 1 Build ') {

      }
    stage('Job 2 Checkout ') {

      }
    stage('Job 2 Build ') {

      }
    }
  }
```

and so on

Comment: job 1,2,3 are regularly  tested. so I'm guessing it'll need to be a separate job instead of job 4. Do you still recommend all 3 jobs in job 4?

Job1,2,3 have other tasks other than just build.. like updating jira etc.,

Comment: yes that's also possible

Comment: what is the other alternative?

Comment: I want all 3 jobs separate. Then Job 4 just need to check if all 3 jobs were successful and if so, it'll re-build all 3 modules  inside job 4 (like you showed) or just pull code for all 3modules and then proceed with other stuff. The only question is how can I check all 3 job status within jenkinsfile?